# How can I import an existing Blockchain.info wallet to bitcoin-cli?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-cli, wallet-import, private-key-import

I manage several accounts which I created via Blockchain.info for my webapp. I'm migrating to bitcoin-cli instead of using their API due to the high amount of calls I have to make.

I'm a bitcoin-cli noob. I have been able to send raw transactions in hex, but I cannot find how to import an existing account to my bitcoin-cli install. Is it possible to do this?

The ultimate goal is to get balance and received transactions of all addresses I have on Blockchain info via bitcoin-cli.

Is this at all doable?

Thanks,
Alberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to export your private keys from Blockchain.info (a bit of googling showed me this: https://github.com/OmniLayer/omniwallet/wiki/Exporting-Private-Key-from-Blockchain.info-and-Importing-to-Omniwallet.org) and then import it in bitcoind using the `import` function (as described in https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Find the 'Import/Export' tab and you can find what you're looking for there.

https://blockchain.info/wallet/backups

Once you find your addresses, click "More options" and then click the private key button. I believe there was also a script somewhere but that's... gone?

Once done, go to your bitcoin-cli and use the `import` function like mentioned above

Comment: Thanks! I did this, but it bound my private key to a different address to the one given on blockchain info. I need that address for customers to interact with my webapp